# Inject object reference in angular controller on instantiation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following problem:

I'm building a self-declaring app and it needs to register a ButtonCtrl but the instantiated object needs to have a reference to an external object outside Angular. I need some properties of that instance passed to the $scope of the controller.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("ButtonCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var myExternalInstance = [WHERE TO GET THIS];
    $scope.testProp = myExternalInstance.test;
}]);
```

I do not know how to add this property on instantiation of the controller.

Comment: What exactly is "an external object outside Angular"?
If you have stored it somewhere you can access it in a controller like in every other js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you all your JS codes reside in the same closure, there is no problem getting it:

```
(function(){
    //assuming we have some jQuery/javascript code here:
    var toBePassedToAngular = "Pass this string to angular";

    //and this is our angular code
    angular.module('myApp').controller("ButtonCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        //access the variable just like normal js code
       var myExternalInstance = toBePassedToAngular;
       $scope.testProp = myExternalInstance;
    }]);
})();
```

and `{{testProp}}` will be evaluated to `Pass string to angular`

However note that you will only get the instance once when the controller is instantiated. Angular will not know if you have made changes to `toBePassedToAngular`. To constantly watch the changes happened to `toBePassedToAngular` and handle the changes to it, it's another whole new story.